# Why no informations get scraped?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, lxml

I am trying to extract information from the epicgames website. I have tested my code below with different websites and it work but for some reason on the epicgames website I get no result when I scrape informations... and I can't figure out why.

In the example below the text "Your Community Awaits" should be print, but it's not working.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

LOGIN_URL = "https://accounts.epicgames.com"

def main():
    session_requests = requests.session()
    result = session_requests.get(LOGIN_URL)
    tree = html.fromstring(result.content)
    text_result = tree.xpath("//div[@class='modalContent']/h3/text()")
    print(text_result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: They might be serving different content because they know you're using requests

Comment: Print `result.content` and see what it looks like? If that's all fine, check your `tree` more closely.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn’t work?

**What does "doesn't work" mean?** "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get an error message? If you did get an error, paste the entire message instead of paraphrasing. Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.